# I clicked the wrong triage action but then went back and voted to close it - is it possible to end a suspension early?

Tags: support, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

Yesterday I accidentally clicked *Requires Editing* while reviewing the triage queue. https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26820044 I didn't mean to do that. It was obvious to me that it should be closed.  I couldn't change my vote but I did flag it to be [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63173161/2350083) outside of the queue.

Because I attempted to fix my mistake - is there any chance a moderator would be willing to end my suspension early?

Comment: mis-clicks happen to everyone and since you did try to correct things and have asked here on meta - there's no problem in removing the review suspension. Thanks for your help!